# Webhook for iTunes Connect crashes?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am able to get the crashes when I go to Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Crashes:

[image]

I was wondering, if it is possible to get a webhook whenever a crash gets sent to itunes (not other crash reporting like Crashlytics, Hockeyapp, etc.), that way I can get real time notifications using Slack whenever a production crash occurs.

Is this feasible?  My only concern is that provisioning profiles and credentials will block me from doing so.  I haven't been able to find any resources online for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bounty worthy answer: I dont think so. It'd be a cool hack (very cool) but I dont there is any public api

Comment: well since youre the only one that answered, you get the prize :)

Answer (score 1):

If one traces http activity whilst downloading crashes on the Xcode Organizer, one can see that `GET` commands are made to http://crashwebservices.apple.com

Right click on Charles to `Copy cURL Request` and the command is executed succesfully in Terminal.

Having removed sensitive information, it looks something like this:

```
curl -H 'Host: crashwebservices.apple.com' -H 'X-Apple-I-Identity-Id: myIdentityId' -H 'User-Agent: Xcode' -H 'X-Apple-GS-Token: myToken' -H 'X-Apple-I-MD-LU: myMDId' -H 'X-Apple-App-Info: com.apple.gs.xcode.auth' -H 'X-Mme-Device-Id: myDeviceId' -H 'X-MMe-Client-Info: <MacBookPro11,3> <Mac OS X;10.13.2;17C205> <com.apple.AuthKit/1 (com.apple.dt.Xcode/13772)>' -H 'X-Apple-I-TimeZone: CET' -H 'X-Apple-I-Client-Time: 2018-02-02T08:43:21Z' -H 'X-Xcode-Version: 9.2 (9C40b)' -H 'Accept-Language: en-gb' -H 'X-Apple-I-MD-RINFO: 17106176' -H 'X-Request-ID: myRequestID' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-Apple-I-MD-M: myMDM' -H 'X-Apple-I-Locale: en_GB' -H 'X-Apple-I-MD: myIMD==' --compressed 'https://crashwebservices.apple.com/api/v2/crashpoint/816170169/com.myappbundleid/2.2.0/2.2.0/iOS/someOtherId?isBeta=false&startDate=2018-01-19&endDate=2018-02-02'
```

A load of data is returned. Most likely all the crash logs.

There will be some authentication handshake first with [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) credentials passed to return a session cookie. In theory you could dig into this and probably have something working.

Finally, looks like you - and I - aren't the first to consider this. See [Crashes Organizer - Crash Web Services](https://github.com/fastlane-old/spaceship/issues/142). Looks like this has since evolved into [Spaceship](https://spaceship.airforce/), which is now part of [fastlane tools](https://fastlane.tools/). Haven't tried it but definitely worth investigating to see if it does everything you need.